# "Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts" in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, wma

I converted wma to mp3:

```
  find -name "*.wma" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -acodec libmp3lame -ab 224k {}.mp3 \;
```

During the conversation process I got warning messages for all media files

```
[mp3 @ 0x1de53e0] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 11567 >= 10662
```

But converted files played without problems. How critical is the message in this case?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the files play fine, you don't have to worry about it.

It means that in the input file, the timestamps associated with samples are not increasing monotonically. That shouldn't be the case, but I think that ffmpeg will usually correct these problems on its own.

If you are using an outdated ffmpeg version, updating to a newer one may help resolve these issues, in case it's a problem with the decoder rather than the actual input files.

Comment: @slhck - Thank you!